# Razorpay Authentication Failed issue in the webview

Tags: payment-gateway, payment, razorpay

I am using the Razorpay payment method in my application.
The issue is whenever a customer tries to make a payment on Razorpay it shows me an ***Authentication Failed*** error, we have a valid Razorpay Client Id, but still it shows me the ***Authentication Failed*** error. Due to the Authentication Failed error I am not able to open the razorpay iframe.

We are showing a web page in the mobile application.

***Note: Not all the users are facing this issue, some of our users are facing this issue. Most of the users can make successful payments from our app, but some get this error.***

The JS version of RazorPay: https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js

Also, there's no error handler method in Razorpay which handles this error, so we can show user to some another message, they have the below method but it works when the actual payment failed

```
rzp1.on('payment.failed', function (response){
    alert(response.error.description);
});
```

**My code for that**

```
var options = {
    "key": "rzp_test_345345345",
    "amount": amount, // 2000 paise = INR 20
    "name": name,
    "description": description,
    "modal.backdropclose": false,
    "modal.escape": true,
    "handler": function(response) {
        $("div#contentContainer").show();
        var razorpay_payment_id = response.razorpay_payment_id;
        if (razorpay_payment_id != '') {
            alert(razorpay_payment_id);
        }
    },
    "prefill": {
        "email": 'test@gmail.com',
        "name": 'test',
        "contact": '8529631478'
    },
    "notes": {
        "order_id": "34343",
        "payment_type": "Test notes"
    },
    "theme": {
        "color": "#F37254"
    },
    "modal": {
        "ondismiss": function() {
            alert('Modal Closed');
        }
    }
};
var rzp1 = new Razorpay(options);
rzp1.on('payment.failed', function (response){
    alert(response.error.description);
});

document.getElementById('pay_now').onclick = function(e) {
    rzp1.open();
    e.preventDefault();
}
$('#pay_now').trigger('click');
```

[image: Error message which I am gettig from razorpay]

We also contact the razorpay support, but there's not a proper response from their side.

Any help would be grateful for me. Thank you in advanced.